# Accelerate import of table of numbers

Tags: performance-tuning, import

I've been writing a `ServiceConnection` to the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/) and one thing I need to do is import large sequences of numbers, like [this one](https://oeis.org/A001006/b001006.txt).

My first though for this was to use `ImportString` as a `"Table"` but this was surprisingly slow (although of course dominated by the download time):

```
seqString = Import["https://oeis.org/A001006/b001006.txt", "Text"];

{t1, r1} = ImportString[seqString, "Table"] // RepeatedTiming;
t1

0.17
```

Then I tried a method using `ReadList`:

```
{t2, r2} =
  Module[
    {stream},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
     stream = StringToStream@seqString,
     ReadList[stream, {Number, Number}],
     Close@stream
     ]
    ] // RepeatedTiming;
t2

0.0090
```

It's unsurprising, but still impressive, how much faster this is.

I then wanted this to be completely general, so I wrote a little wrapper to guess the table-width and registered it as an import format:

```
iImportNumTable[stream_InputStream, colNum_Integer?Positive] :=
  ReadList[stream, ConstantArray[Number, colNum]];
iImportNumTable[stream_InputStream, Optional[Automatic, Automatic]] :=
  Module[
   {
    l1 = ReadList[stream, String, 1][[1]]
    },
   If[StringQ@l1, 
    l1 = ImportString[l1, "Table"];
    Join[
     l1,
     iImportNumTable[stream, Length@l1[[1]]]
     ],
    $Failed
    ]
   ];
Options[ImportNumTable] =
  {
   "TableWidth" -> Automatic
   };
ImportNumTable[stream_InputStream, ops : OptionsPattern[]] :=
  iImportNumTable[stream, OptionValue["TableWidth"]];
ImportExport`RegisterImport[
 "NumberTable",
 ImportNumTable,
 "FunctionChannels" -> {"Streams"},
 "BinaryFormat" -> True
 ]
```

This remains fast, and is much more general:

```
{t3, r3} = ImportString[seqString, "NumberTable"] // RepeatedTiming;
t3

0.014

r3 == r1

True
```

And the boost is even more dramatic as the table size scales up. Here's a plot that shows how this scales (with the x-axis being number of times `seqString` is repeated).

```
tabDat =
  Table[
   With[{s = StringRiffle[ConstantArray[seqString, n], "\n"]},
    {
     {n, ImportString[s, "NumberTable"] // RepeatedTiming // First},
     {n, ImportString[s, "Table"] // RepeatedTiming // First}
     }
    ],
   {n, {5, 10 , 15, 25}}
   ];
ListLinePlot[Transpose@tabDat, PlotLegends -> {"NumberTable", "Table"}]
```

[image]

But I want to know if we can do better/simpler.

Whats the fastest/minimal code way we can import a rectangular table of numbers?

Comment: Shouldn't `ReadList[stream,Number,RecordLists->True]` eliminate the need for guessing the table width?

Comment: @LukasLang ahh I always forget about that option. You're right. That's much cleaner.